# How to pass xsrf cookie to host?

Tags: python, curl, python-2.7, tornado

In Tornado app I put settings for

settings = dict(
    cookie_secret="11oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/",
    xsrf_cookies=True,
    autoescape="xhtml_escape",
)
(copied from web, gonna change cookie_secret) and I am trying to execute from command line using curl

```
curl -d "name=Paola&last_name=James" --header "X-CSRFToken:11oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/" http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration
```

and I got error like

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'X-CSRFToken:11oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o'
<html><title>403: Forbidden</title><body>403: Forbidden</body></html>
```

How to pass xsrf to  host?

Answer (score 1):

XSRF must be passed in the cookie header, [and in the form data OR `X-CSRFToken`/`X-XSRFToken`](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L924):

```
curl -d "name=Paola&last_name=James&_xsrf=11oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/" --cookie "_xsrf=11oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/; Path=/" http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration
```

or

```
curl -d "name=Paola&last_name=James" --cookie "_xsrf=11oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/; Path=/" --header "X-CSRFToken: 11oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/" http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration
```